# не отправляет смс с сайта

Tags: php, html

```
    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $to = "balayan.mher88@gmail.com"; 
    $from = $_POST['email']; // thims is the sender's Email address
    $first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
    $subject = "Форма отправки сообщений с сайта";
    $subject2 = "Copy of your form submission";
    $message = $first_name . " оставил сообщение:" . "\n\n" . $_POST['message'];
    $message2 = "Here is a copy of your message " . $first_name . "\n\n" . $_POST['message'];
    $headers = "From:" . $from;
    $headers2 = "From:" . $to;
    mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
    // mail($from,$subject2,$message2,$headers2); // sends a copy of the message to the sender - Отключено!
    echo "Ձեր հաղորդագրությունը ուղղարկվել Է։Շնորհակալություն " . $first_name . ", Արևիկը Ձեզ հետ շուտով կկապնվի։";
    echo "<br /><br /><a href=</a>";
    }
    ?>
    <!--Переадресация на главную страницу сайта, через 3 секунды-->
    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
    function changeurl(){eval(self.location="http://localhost/aaaa");}
    window.setTimeout("changeurl();",9000);
    </script>
<form action="send.php" method="post">
                 <input type="text" name="first_name"><br>
                    <input type="text" name="email" required placeholder=""><br>
                <br><textarea rows="5" name="message" cols="30"></textarea><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Вы с localhost хотите отправить сообщение? Или скрипт не работает на сервере?

Comment: из localhost, но  не получаетсья

Comment: Если вы с домашнего компьютера пытаетесь протестировать и у вас установлен какой-нибудь локальный сервер, то нужно смотреть настройки -

Comment: не подскажетье что за настройки?

Comment: У вас какой сервер установлен?

Comment: сервер у меня  Mamp  .

Comment: По MAMP нужно документацию смотреть, как пример Openserver: https://proctoline.ru/otpravka-email-v-php-nastrojka-openserver#_php_SMTP - посмотрите то же самое по вашему серверу

Comment: Здесь нет ни строчки кода которая оправляла бы смс. Емейл да, смс - нет.